# Change horizontal value axis on matlab

Tags: matlab, fft, frequency-analysis

I am very new in Matlab and I want to plot a function using stem like this:

```
% Taller de analisis de frecuencias %
n = 0:3999;
Fs = 8000;
x1 = sin(2*pi*1000/Fs*n); 
subplot(3,1,1);
stem(x1(1:9));
disp('FFT con N=4096');
nfft = 4096;
y = fft(x1,nfft);
subplot(3,1,2);
stem(y);
subplot(3,1,3);
stem(fftshift(y));
```

I am using this as part of a study to learn to analyze frequencies from analog to digital signal transformation. The thing is I want to label in the second stem the horizontal axis with the values from 0 to 2*pi (which are the correct values for representing the signal), then I have to cut the second part of the representation and move it to the front (the result will be the 3th stem (actually this one is obtained using fftshift function which is the same as I cutting and pasting in front)

I can not be able to label the horizontal axis with the values from 0:2*pi so I am asking for help because I know this can be done..

Thank you so much

Comment: Not sure why you want to label the frequency domain data with 0..2 PI but you can define the support of the plot by providing the x-data as vector to `stem`: `stem(linspace(0,2*pi,numel(y)), abs(fftshift(y)));`. Note that as you script stands, you plot the imaginary part of `y` against the real part of `y` which is probably not what you want. I therefore added the `abs()`.

Comment: @Deve for discrete signal processing, you are normally interested in the frequency compared to its sampling frequency. That may for example be normalized from 0 ot 2*pi. But, Neteot you can use the syntax `stem(X,Y,...)` to get the right values on the x-axis.

Comment: @patrik The normalized angular frequency, right.

Comment: thank @patrik, at the first glance thats what i tried but I don't know exactly how to do it, I've tried that before with plot function, I want to match each of the 4096 points of the x axis to their relative 0:2*pi points..but don't have any idea of how to do it

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion by Deve in a comment solves the problem you stated: use `stem(X,Y)` where X is a vector of the same length as Y, with desired endpoints. Such a vector is created with `linspace` command.

You may also want to use `axis tight` in order to not leave empty space that looks like a region of zero frequencies. Here's what I get after these adjustments:

[image: myplot]

and this is the code:

```
n = 0:3999;
Fs = 8000;
x1 = sin(2*pi*1000/Fs*n); 
subplot(3,1,1);
stem(x1(1:9));
disp('FFT con N=4096');
nfft = 4096;
y = fft(x1,nfft);
subplot(3,1,2);
stem( linspace(0,2*pi, length(y)), y);
axis tight
subplot(3,1,3);
stem( linspace(-pi,pi, length(y)), fftshift(y));
axis tight
```